# How to launch a python GUI application from crontab or rc.local?

Tags: python, cron

It needs to be run as root to work properly. I've tried:

```
DISPLAY=:0 /usr/bin/gtk-launch myapp
DISPLAY=:0 /usr/bin/python /my/application/gui.py
```

The second line is basically what's inside of the myapp.desktop. Both lines work in terminal (ctr+alt+t) and emulated console (ctrl+alt+F1) and don't work in rc.local and crontab. Is the latter possible? If not, then why?

UPDATE:
I believe that putting a script being an analog of crontab into /etc/xdg/autostart/mycrontab.desktop would be a workaround. However, I am curious about how to do this with crontab & rc.local.

Comment: You may need to add the full path to the executables. The PATH environement variable is not yet available at the time rc.local is run.

Comment: No, this does not work. If I use /usr/share/applications/myapp.desktop instead of myapp, then it does not work at all.

Comment: A .desktop file cannot be run directly from the command line. Needs to be an executable binary or a script.

Comment: It runs from command line in terminal and console pretty well.

Comment: The command ` /usr/share/applications/myapp.desktop` as such? Anyway, make sure the command is executed at a moment where the X-server is fully up and running. It is not yet when rc.local is executed.

Comment: I use gtk-launch in the command line. Ok, crontab executes when X-server is fully up and running. I used to run disowned script with those lines with a delay, so rc.local had to be covered too.

Comment: Shouldn't gtk not also be up and running before the command can work? Is there absolutely no way to avoid a graphical user interface for this kind of needs? This appears against common practice to me.

Comment: I am not sure about gtk. What should I check then? It is the GUI application. It has been confusing to me, this difference between console and rc.local & crontab. This problem should be solved.

Comment: Looks like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) to me. What are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is inspired by [Starting Rhythmbox via crontab](https://askubuntu.com/questions/473269/starting-rhythmbox-via-crontab?rq=1) . This

```
XAUTHORITY=/home/name/.Xauthority DISPLAY=:0 /usr/bin/gtk-launch myapp
```

or this

```
XAUTHORITY=/home/name/.Xauthority DISPLAY=:0 gtk-launch myapp
```

works. Then you also need the file `/usr/share/applications/myapp.desktop` with the command inside:

```
sudo -b /usr/bin/python /my/application/gui.py
```

I use `sudo -b` to hide popping up terminal window.

The reason was that "the root in the terminal" and "the root in rc.local & crontab" have different environment variables. It is interesting that if I also set, say, `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-wpHtRgNiWP`, taken from a user, then it does not work.